# Can you Pass Secret to Custom Element?

Tags: html, web-component, custom-element, secret-key

This might be a stretch, but is there a method of providing a secret attribute or property to a custom element that cannot be inspected as an attribute or property?

Case scenario . . . a widget that has some API calls that require a secure token. The toke itself is a special hash of a private key, and is generated and stashed as a private property within the web component when the component mounts to keep it all under wraps.

`<custom-element secret="******"></..>`

But how to get the private key in there initially? Assume the custom element can be used anywhere in the end user's application, using any front end library or build process. Even fed in from a global store or broader web app.

I cannot think of how you could send that data in without it becoming visible at some point as an attribute or property . . . unless there's a technique I am aware of.

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Anything sent to the browser is visible to the browser, and accessible to the user via client side tools; security through obscurity isn't a viable strategy I'm afraid, though this is both by-design and a feature which has more benefits than problems.

Comment: You can't secure client-side keys, you can only delay hackers by adding multiple decoding layers. If your question is about hosting a Web Component, I blogged about an extra layer of "security" [here](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/protecting-your-web-components-but-you-did-not-hear-this-from-me-3b59) ... but don't tell the hackers

Comment: Got it . . very useful tips here from @Danny'365CSI'Engelman. I very much appreciate the resources and ideas!